# When do I create a separate entity when drawing conceptual models?

Tags: database-design, erd

I have these 3 scenarios:

**Rooms located in a house are assigned a room number within that house - thus, for example, each house has a room number 1. Each room has a phone number etc...**

My guess is we do not need to have a separate entity for rooms since each house must have one room then if we delete the room we should delete the house anyway?

**A tour guide(identified by tour guide id) may have one or more specialisations but not all tour guides have them.**

Specialisations should be a separate class?

**If an activity is performed by a Tourism Provider do not record the details of the Tourism Provider who completed the activity.**

Should Tourism Provider even be a separate entity because we are not recording the details?

Comment: "Rooms located in a house are assigned a room number within that house" seems to me to allow multiple rooms in a house (which seems more reasonable than saying there can only be 1). It also states that the room numbers in each house start at 1 (which affects the logical id of a room). So rooms very definitely need a separate entity.

Comment: If the scenario specifically says not to record details of the entity should it even be modelled in the diagram? Referring to the updated third scenario.

Comment: Take that to its logical extreme: you'll have a completely empty diagram with no entities.